# Is there any standard/guideline to follow on HW testing as ISO9126?

Tags: test-management, standards, hardware

For software, it is often beneficial to use `ISO9126/25010` as a roadmap for test coverage (e.g. functionality, reliability ...) and I wonder, is there something like that for HW?
Some categorization I could use as a checklist of basic "areas for testing"?

Comment: What sort of "Hardware" - are we talking a hammer or a space shuttle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our site is currently scoped to software as indicated in the title